# Pass question mark (?) character to angular component but hide the ? from user input

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an HTML input element that when a user enters a ? it opens a MatDialog window. I need to still pass the ? value to the openLookupDialog method that opens the MatDialog but I want to hide/mask the ? from the user.

Here's my code example:

```
 <input matInput aria-label="State" 
     [formControl]="countryLookupModalDialogForm" 
     (keyup)="openLookupDialog($event)"
     class="lookup-input" [ngModel]="countryModalDialogLookupInput">
```

```
  openLookupDialog(event: any): void {
    if (event.target.value !== '?') {
      return;
    }

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(LookupdialogComponent, {width: '450px'});
    dialogRef.componentInstance.rowSelected.subscribe(result => {
      this.doSetResult(result);
    });
```

Comment: Are you able to create a fiddle for me to play around with?

Comment: Thanks Dylan, I've created a StackBlitz to demo the code [code demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zaobfh). I need the ? to be passed to the countryLookupModalDialogForm() function, but the user should not see the ? character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a play around in the stackBlitz you created for me, and thank you for doing that, I hope what I have come up with is able to help you find a solution that best use your use case.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';

  countryLookupModalDialogForm = new FormControl();

  openLookupDialog(event: any): void {

  /******/
  // Below is a possible solution if you want to use '?' as a forbidden char
  /******/

 const str = event.target.value;
 const regexp = /[?]/gi; // really good site to explore this further: https://regexr.com/
 const found = str.match(regexp);

 console.log(found);
 if (found != null) { 
   console.log(' Do what you will :)');
 }

 /******/
 // Below is a possible solution if your only worried about the first character
 /******/

 if (event.target.value !== '?') {
   return;
 }
 event.target.value = '';

 setTimeout(() => {
   window.alert('MatDialog Opened Successfully!')
 },100); // Give the value enough time to change before alert box activates (0.1 second)

 }
}
```